# Adding entries to map: _Block_Type_Is_Valid (pHead->nBlockUse)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stdmap

**Update**

The problem was caused by using pointers as key for the maps. As it seems that doesn't really work :-D

**Original Post**

I want to store calls to my renderer and then render them in sorted order. I thought it would be a good idea to have a map taking a shader as argument and a map of < SomeKey, SomeOtherMap > as value. At the end of this there would be a vector of properties.

I tried it with the following code:

```
/* Typedefs */
typedef std::vector< Properties > PropertiesLayerOpaque;
typedef std::map< GeometryPtr, PropertiesLayerOpaque > GeometryLayerOpaque;
typedef std::map< MaterialPtr, GeometryLayerOpaque > MaterialLayerOpaque;
typedef std::map< ShaderPtr, MaterialLayerOpaque > QueueOpaque;

void RenderQueue::submitToRenderQueue(GeometryPtr geometry, Properties properties, GLfloat distanceToCamera, bool opaque)
{
    if (opaque){
        MaterialLayerOpaque &matLayer = _renderQueueOpaque[geometry->getMaterial()->getShader()];
        GeometryLayerOpaque &geomLayer = matLayer[geometry->getMaterial()];
        PropertiesLayerOpaque &propertiesLayer = geomLayer[geometry];
        propertiesLayer.push_back(properties);
    }
}
```

Shaders, Materials and Geometry are shared_ptr because I work with them everywhere in my project. The properties are added by value since they should be unique and basically define the call to the renderer.

Now to my problem: This code works fine until I add the same model (with the same shader, material and geometry but different properties) a second time. 
The call is added but at the end of the function I get the following Error:

[image: error message]

I don't really get these maps as it seems, so I really appreciate your help ... Thank you so much!

Comment: As far as i know this assertion occurs when you free unallocated memory, can you identify the source of the problem when you go back in the call stack?

Comment: As I said it happens when I add the same geometry, shader and material a second time but with other properties. This calls my function "submitToRenderQueue" and at the end of this function (last curly bracket) it seems to do something that it shouldn't. In the call stack it sais that it calls [External Code] and then some other stuff. Here's a screenshot: http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150722/i3aq5vz2.png

Comment: I would add debug output to the constructor of your objects and then compare the addresses with the one that gets deleted.

Comment: I found out that the problem was caused by using pointers as key in the map. I changed that and it works now. I'll update my initial post ;-)